# How to default both a formik date and time field to display a placeholder value

Tags: reactjs, datepicker, formik, timepicker, formik-material-ui

I am working on a project that is using Formik for React specifically the following NPM package - https://www.npmjs.com/package/formik-material-ui-pickers

I am using the code from the CodeSandbox link/example within this npm package for both -

https://codesandbox.io/s/915qlr56rp?file=/src/index.tsx:4770-4987

```
    <Field component={TimePicker} name="time" label="Time" />
    <Field component={DatePicker} name="date" label="Date" />
```

My question is, instead of a date and time appearing at start-up, how can I default the date to display **DD-MM-YYYY** as a placeholder as well as default the time to display **HH:MI:SS** as a placeholder?

Only when the user selects a date and time, do I want it to display and update Formik's initialValues.

I have checked the doco over at https://material-ui-pickers.dev/api/TimePicker and https://material-ui-pickers.dev/api/DatePicker and cannot see anything that will allow a default or placeholder value.

Answer (score 1):

You need to do a custom DatePicker and put format into it

**Solution**

```js
const CustomDatePicker = ({...props}) => (
    <DatePicker format="dd-MM-yyyy" {...props} />
);

<Field component={CustomDatePicker} name="date" label="Date" />
// Do similar for TimePicker
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your post but I think you may have not understood my question correctly. I am ok with the format of the date being `format="dd-MM-yyyy"` but what I am actually after is a default value of null and a placeholder value that shows the format needs to be in `"dd-MM-yyyy"`` but to begin with, I need the date to be null. Hope this makes sense. If not, pls let me know.